# Isolate Scope 2 way bindings doesn't update the value of parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, isolate-scope

Hello I have directive foo in which controller I have

```
$scope.valid = false
```

I am passing this variable inside another directive through isolated scoping in my template

```
<bar valid="valid">
```

and using an ng-if inside my template

```
<span ng-if="valid">Validated<span>
```

Now when I update valid in my child directive. It shows validated in my template. But the variable did not update in my parent directive controller. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: In my child controller I am attaching the variable to controller instead of scope. Is this the reason it is behaving like this.

Indeed, if, in your child directive controller code, you write

```
function MyController($scope) {
    this.valid = $scope.valid;
}
```

then setting the controller object's `valid` property is not going to change the `$scope.valid`, because you performed a copy of `valid`.

Instead, keep using `$scope` to pass the information about the change back up to the parent.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I meant binding to controller using bindToController: true. Anyway this was not causing issue. I checked it by removing bindToController and using scope.